# MySQL syntax error : where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to insert a record in the database if it does not already exists and this is the query:

```
insert into evt(e_id, t_id)
values( '1597',  '4')
where not exists( select id from evt where e_id = '4' and t_id = '1597');
```

that query returns with the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists( select id from evt where e_id = '4' and t_id = ' at line 1

I can't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: that dml usage is not valid. you can refer to here. [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE condition

```
 insert into evt(e_id, t_id) values( '1597',  '4')
```

could be you need  update

```
  update evt
  set e_id = '1597',
  t_id  = 4
  where id  not in ( select id from evt where e_id = '4' and t_id = '1597');
```

Or an insert select

```
 insert into evt(e_id, t_id) 
 select  '1597',  '4'
 from evt
 where not exists( select id from evt where e_id = '4' and t_id = '1597');
```

Comment: *Insert have not where condition* that's a total misleading statement .. though your answer if correct.

Comment: @Rahul  correct  .. mySQL insert have not  a where  .. condition

Comment: @DomeWTF . . . This is definitely not the best way to address this situation.  A unique index or constraint is the right way.

Comment: This is also possibly subject to race condition issues (i.e. does not guarantee that there will be no duplicated). This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747327/299774 does not suffer from that problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prevent duplicates in the database, then let the database do the work.  Use a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_evt_eid_tid on evt(e_id, t_id);
```

This guarantees the data integrity, regardless of how values are inserted or updated.  The database does the work for you.

Then you can prevent an error when inserting, by using `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into evt(e_id, t_id)
     values (1597,  4) 
     on duplicate key update e_id = values(e_id);
```

The `on duplicate key` prevents the code from generating an error.

I also removed the single quotes from the values.  Ids are usually numbers.  If they are really strings, add the quotes back in.

Comment: I would have liked to do this, but the two keywords cannot be unique by themselves they are unique as a pair

Comment: could this be the answer? ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable
ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2 )

Comment: @DomeWTF . . . I don't get the issue.  This defines the pair to be unique, not each column separately.

Comment: yes, the table is for tags, i want e_id not to be unique and the same for t_id, but i don't want to insert a row in which e_id and t_id are equal to another row. There can be values like 4, 1000 | 4, 1003 | 3, 1000, ecc... but not duplicates like 4, 1000 | 4, 1000 | ecc... where the pair already exists

Comment: @DomeWTF . . . That is exactly what this code does.  Hence, I don't understand your original comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    INSERT INTO evt(e_id, t_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '4', '1597') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT e_id FROM evt WHERE e_id = '4' and t_id = '1597'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 insert into evt(e_id, t_id) values( '1597',  '4') where not in( select id from evt where e_id = '4' and t_id = '1597');
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT statement doesn't support WHERE clause.

You have multiple options. First do a select and if the condition is true INSERT OR Use ON DUPLICATE KEY

```
INSERT INTO evt
    SET e_id = '1597', t_id = '4'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    e_id = '1597', t_id = '4'
```

This needs your field to be an index ( Primary or unique )

Note: you shouldn't use quotes when inserting numbers as the mysql treat it like a string and tries to do a conversion and gradually it slows down your project. Also it is safer to insert numbers **without quotes**

Answer (score 0):

I solved everything adding a unique pair like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **UPDATE** and not insert?

```
UPDATE `evt` SET `e_id`='1597', `t_id`='4' 
       WHERE `e_id` NOT in ('4') and `t_id` not in('1597');
```